# robot_state_publisher and joint_state_publisher in launch file

Tags: roslaunch, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I personally got stuck when setting up my robot. I followed the [tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/index.html) and by the end it seems to work. Now I want to launch only the EKF from robot_localization package (which works) but I need to launch a robot_state_publisher and a joint_state_publisher as well. When I comment all code lines containing Gazebo etc. the execution fails. The robot's properties as joints etc. are defined in an URDF-file.
Therefore my question: How can I run the two publishing nodes correctly from the launch-file? There is no GUI needed.

I really hope anyone can help me.

Regards s0nc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390730/robot_state_publisher-and-joint_state_publisher-in-launch-file/) by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you're using `xacro`, one can do something like

```
from amenx_index_python import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    my_xacro = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("PKG_NAME"),
        "urdf",
        "ROBOT_NAME.urdf.xacro",
    )

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            Node(
                package="joint_state_publisher",
                executable="joint_state_publisher",
                name="joint_state_publisher",
            ),
            Node(
                package="robot_state_publisher",
                executable="robot_state_publisher",
                name="robot_state_publisher",
                parameters=[
                    {
                        "robot_description": Command(["xacro", " ", my_xacro]),
                    }
                ],
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Of course it is hard to know what your problem is without knowing more regarding the error output.

Note: this code was taken from a foxy pkg running on ubuntu 20.04.

---

Originally posted by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) with karma: 198 on 2021-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on 2021-11-15**:
Thank you for your help!! It finally works.